# How to detect object is cascade deleted by coredata

Tags: core-data

I have two entities: Folder <-->> Document, and Folder defines a To-Many relationship to Document with a cascade delete rule. My question is: is there some way for document object itself to detect when it is cascade deleted ?

Answer (score 1):

Your Document should receive a [`-[NSManagedObject validateForDelete:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-BBCJCJBF) message. You can also check whether an `NSManagedObject` is deleted (or scheduled for deletion) with [`-[NSManagedObject isDeleted]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-BBCCDJAI). So your Document's methods can perform the check on `[self isDeleted]`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried both of them. -[NSManagedObject validateForDelete:] is not I want. I want to check the delete status sometime later, not be notified during -[NSManagedObjectContext save:], and -[NSManagedObject validateForDelete:] will be called twice for each document, I don't know why. -[NSManagedObject isDeleted] did work if I delete Document directly, but If I delete Folder， -[document isDeleted] always return NO before and after -[NSManagedObjectContext save:]